# Closed form expression for 3F2 with positive unit argument

Tags: special-functions, hypergeometric-function

Is there any closed form expression for the Hypergeometric function 
${}_3F_2(-n,-n,c;-d/2-n,-d/2-n;1)$ for $n>0$ and $d>0$. The parameter $c$ can be both positive and negative.

Comment: May we assume $n\in\mathbb{N}$? Or are you hoping for something possibly more general?

Comment: We can assume $n \ \in\ {\mathbb{N}}$